# I am trying to form 7 groups of random number of observations from a total of 100 observations. All observations should be used

Tags: r, sampling, replicate

I am trying to create a list of 7 groups with 100 observations. Each group can have different number of observations. All observations should be placed in one of the 7 groups. In other words, all observations should be used.

The code I am using does not use all the observations. Is there a way that I can solve this?

```
times_to_sample = 7L
  NN = nrow(df)
  sample<-replicate(times_to_sample, df[sample(NN, sample(5:15, 1L)), ], simplify = FALSE)
```

my expected result just has to place each observation in one of the seven groups. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Generate 100 observations from 1 to 7, and assign accordingly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Form 7 groups each group with 10-15 observations from 100 observations without replacement. (R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57231567/form-7-groups-each-group-with-10-15-observations-from-100-observations-without-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
group_indices <- sample(x = 1:7, size = 100, replace = TRUE)

df_splitted_in_7_groups <- split(x = df, f = group_indices)
```

Comment: is there a way I can limit the minimum number of observations in each group?

Comment: @Shand I'm not aware of an elegant method, but you can do `group_indices<-sample(x = c(rep.int(x = 1:7, times = k), sample(x = 1:7, size = (100 - (7 * k)), replace = TRUE)))`, where `k` is the minimum number of observations per group. If you want to have different minimum number of observations per group, supply a vector of length `7` as the `times` argument.